# Change H1 color on Jekyll, Just the Docs, Github Pages

Tags: css, css-selectors, jekyll, jekyll-theme

I need help changing the H1 color on my website.  The website is a Just the Docs theme on Jekyll and hosted on Github Pages.

I've created the following file and code:

_sass/custom/custom.scss

.h1 { color:#5c5962; }

I am not sure why this is not changing the H1 color, but I am not a CSS/HTML expert, so I'm probably doing something wrong.

Hoping someone can help here.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote `.h1 { ... }`, but "h1" is a tag, not a class, therefore to be written *without* the preceding dot: `h1 { ...}`